# Where is the chrome in Firefox 5 (Windows)?

Tags: firefox

I want to extract one of the animation files (probably a PNG?) I see in the Firefox 5 interface ... where would they be found? I used to be able to find all that kind of thing in a .jar file somewhere in Program Files/Firefox or maybe in Application Data?

Anyway, I can't find files like that now. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, or at least in my particular case (on XP) the answer was:

C:\Documents and Settings\<USERNAME>\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<PROFILE_ID>\extensions\<THEME_ID>\chrome\browser.jar

and browser.jar is of course really a zip file so I just renamed it and opened it.